# Presenting the convergence of a set of distributions to a particular distribution graphically

Tags: distributions, data-visualization

This is not directly related to *doing* statistics, but rather *presenting* statistical data.

I have a set of values $$\{x_i\},{i\in I_t},$$
for each $t\in [0,1]$. Every set of values $\{x_i\}$ for a fixed $t$ gives me a distribution and as $t\to 1$, the distribution of $\{x_i\}$ converges to a particular well-known distribution.

I would like to show this convergence **graphically** in a similar way how $1/n$ sequence converges to $0$. How can I do that? Are there ways of presenting this data such that it will provide an intuition about how fast the date convergence to that particular distribution?

Comment: Why not look at some of our [answers on the topic of graphical display of convergence in distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=converg*+distribution+graph*+is%3Aanswer+score%3A5)?

Comment: @whuber The link does not direct me to any useful question. Plus, when I search it manually, I get a single useless question.

Comment: On the first page of results, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/314995/919, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/153067/919, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/402842/919, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/48383/919, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/387140/919, and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/43075/919 illustrate convergence of distributions in three different ways: via the CDF, the PDF, and the characteristic function.

Comment: @whuber thanks a lot